# Restoring a schema in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, postgresql, backup, database-migration, restore

I have migrated data (test schema) from PostgreSQL to oracle using the postgres drivers. I have then taken a backup for (test schema) from oracle.
Though its dump file I am unable to restore it to the oracle database.I am trying to backup using command prompt.
2.     What ever changes I make in PostgreSQL is getting reflected in oracle and vice-verse. Can i make these two independent.
I am using windows 7 OS.

Comment: Please show us the commands and error-messages.

Comment: HI Bjarte Brandt,

I have figured it out..
Its resolved.

Thank you for giving a thought on this....